# Uninstalling quasar-cli via npm not working?

Tags: npm, npm-install, quasar-framework, quasar

I was working on a Quasar project on my windows machine and out of blue it is saying `quasar is not recognized as an internal or external command.`
I tried to uninstall quasar-cli with the command `npm uninstall -g quasar-cli` but it seems it is not working. `npm list -g --depth=0` command tells me that I still have the quasar-cli.

```
C:\Users\nitin>npm uninstall -g quasar-cli
up to date in 0.028s
```

```
C:\Users\nitin>npm list -g --depth=0
C:\Users\nitin\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- @quasar/cli@1.1.0
+-- cordova@9.0.0
+-- nodemon@2.0.4
`-- vue-cli@2.9.6
```

I am also not able to install it again as it gives the following errors

```
C:\Users\nitin>npm install -g quasar-cli
npm WARN deprecated @babel/preset-stage-2@7.0.0-beta.54: � We've deprecated any official stage presets in favor of users explicitly opt-ing into the proposals they want to use versus any perceived convenience. You can also check https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/7770 for more information.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.0.4: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/preset-stage-3@7.0.0-beta.54: � We've deprecated any official stage presets in favor of users explicitly opt-ing into the proposals they want to use versus any perceived convenience. You can also check https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/7770 for more information.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated joi@11.4.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN rollback Rolling back is-descriptor@1.0.2 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\nitin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\quasar-cli\node_modules\define-property\node_modules'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.2 (node_modules\quasar-cli\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0: wanted: {"node":"<8.10.0"} (current: {"node":"12.17.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\quasar-cli\node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.5.1 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path C:\Users\nitin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\quasar-cli\bin\quasar
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\nitin\AppData\Roaming\npm\quasar
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, cmd shim 'C:\Users\nitin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\quasar-cli\bin\quasar' -> 'C:\Users\nitin\AppData\Roaming\npm\quasar'
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\nitin\AppData\Roaming\npm\quasar
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\nitin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-19T04_24_31_029Z-debug.log
```

Can you please suggest where am I going wrong. I am new with npm and JS in general so please correct if I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ultimately had to delete the `node-modules` folder from

```
C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
```

as I was having issue not only with quasar but also with vue and everything else.
`vue --version` also wasn't working.

I deleted the `node-modules` folder from the above path and also from my project folder and then re-installed them using `npm install -g` command. This command needs to be run in your project folder where you have your `package.json` file.

Else you can individually install(globally using the `-g` appended to the command) each component of your need.
Restart the command prompt after installing the packages.
Don't forget to keep a list of all the packages you have using

```
npm list -g --depth=0`
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
npm uninstall -g @quasar/cli
```

Answer (score 1):

I've recently performed a manual delete for a similar issue I was facing, opting instead to use the rimraf package to delete a module from the npm root directory where global packages are installed.

Install rimraf using:

```
npm install rimraf -g
```

Navigate to the root folder of where the global packages are installed. Path to this can be found using:

```
npm root -g
```

Once you've cd' into the root folder perform the delete on the quasar-cli module using:

```
rimraf <name of folder>
```

Note:
`<name of folder>` is the name of the folder quasar-cli is contained within. Perform a `dir/w` to list the folder in the directory to check the exact name of the folder to insert in the command above.

The rimraf package is a cross-platform equivalent of what I use in the bash terminal rm -rf to recursively delete files and folders. You can see this in action on windows via: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qPCK6mWeqsk

Check that the removal of the package as per your previous command:

```
npm list -g --depth=0
```

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks Will_d0g for your answer. It didn't work for me but it might help someone who will come to this question searching for an answer. I have upvoted it.